# Using VBA to get the sum of values based on criteria from other tables?

Tags: sql, database, vba, ms-access

I need to find the sum of the prices of a number of products, however the prices are stored in  a different table to products that need pricing.

But, there is a catch, it needs to select these items based on criteria from a third table too.

So, I need the sum of the price of all products in Table 1 where CutID in Table 2 = 001.

Table 1 and Table 2 are linked on SCID, one to many respectively.

If this makes no sense tell me and I will try to clarify?

Thanks,
Bob P

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question, I don't think there's a need for VBA. Excel formulas should be sufficient.

1. Add a few columns to your primary table.  In these columns, use vlookup() to get all your information in one place, including the criteria.
2. If you only need to sum based on one criteria, use sumif().  If there's multiple criteria, use sumproduct().

Answer (score 1):

Generally, with Access, I initially try to work with something as close a possible to a standard SQL query for ease of maintenance and portability. This ran for me in Access 2010:

```
SELECT Products.ProductID, Sum(Prices.Price) AS PriceSum
FROM Prices INNER JOIN (Critera INNER JOIN Products ON Critera.SCID = Products.SCID) ON Prices.ProductID = Products.ProductID
WHERE Critera.CutID="001"
GROUP BY Products.ProductID;
```

Please let us know if that works with your data (I'm not sure of your column names, either).